# Column vertical SpaceBetween not taking into account

Tags: android, kotlin, alignment, android-jetpack-compose

Can not understand why in this card, in the column, the spacebetween vertical alignment is not taking into account. I'm expecting the Title to be on top, and the "View Details" button to be at the bottom of the Column

```
fun UserCard(image:Int, text:String, actionButtonLabel:String){
    Card(
        elevation = 4.dp,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(12.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
    ) {
        Row(
            horizontalArrangement  =  Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(8.dp)
                .border(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Blue)
                .padding(12.dp)
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = image),
                contentDescription = "",
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(120.dp)
                    .clip(CircleShape)
            )
            Column(
                modifier= Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween, // <-- seems not to be taking into account
            ) {
                Title(text)
                Button(onClick = { }) {
                    Text(text = actionButtonLabel)
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

example of call of UserCard

```
UserCard(
            image= R.drawable.iron,
            text = "Live after death",
            actionButtonLabel = "View details"
        )
```

[image: button tp be at button of the card]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply an [intrinsic measurements](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements) to the `Row` container and the `fillMaxHeight()` Modifier to the `Column`.
Your issue is the height of the column.

```
    Row(
        horizontalArrangement  =  Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
        //..
    ){
        /* Image */
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween){
          
           //...
        }
   }
```

[image]